# Filter list within a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function to populate English marks grater than 60. I don't know how to populate a list within a list

```
type Name = String
type Mark = (String, Int)
data Student = Student Name [Mark]
                deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
students :: [Student]
students = [Student "Ko Ko" [("English", 60), ("Math", 80)], Student "John" [("English", 30), ("Math", 70)], Student "Kathy" [("English", 90), ("Math", 70)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you try to create function which get list of students and return only those of them, which have mark on English greater than 60. So you can try this function:

```hs
studentEnglishFilter :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Student] -> [Student]
studentEnglishFilter p = filter (
    \(Student name marks) ->
        case find ((== "English") . fst) marks of
            Nothing -> False
            Just (_, mark) -> p mark
    )
```

You can run:

```hs
studentEnglishFilter (> 60) students
```

and will see:

```hs
[Student "Kathy" [("English", 90), ("Math", 70)]]
```

But you also can use simple function `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`.